# AssetManager seems to not be working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-assets

I'm trying to load the level image of my libgdx game with an AssetManager, it seemed easy enough from a guide i followed, but i'm having kind of an error..

i'm using this code in a class called Assets.java
package Loader;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class Assets {

    public static final AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static final String level1 = "level1.png";

    public static void load() {
        manager.load(level1, Texture.class);
    }

    public static void dispose() {
        manager.dispose();
    }
}
```

and this code in the main class:

```
@Override
public void create () {

    Assets.load();

    while(!Assets.manager.update()) {
        System.out.println(Assets.manager.getProgress()*100+"%");
    }

    setScreen(new GameScreen());
}
```

but it is always showing me a 0.0% and never loads the image

the file image i'm trying to load weights 300 KB, i've tried with small images too, but nothing changes..

**EDIT**

it immediately goes to the new screen but still prints out 0.0% endlessly never loading the image

Answer (score 3):

Call the `.finishLoading();` if you want to finish loading inside of your create. Else you need to call the `.update()` inside of your gameloop. For more information see [this link.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets)

Moreover i wouldn't make the manager static! You cant guarantee that you just have one of that objects therefore it can happen that if you access an asset you haven't load it at that instance of AssetManager. Whenever you access the manager a new Assetmanager is created and the static method is called. So you would always need to load the assets when you access your manager thats not the right behaviour you whish i think. Create it as regular object and have an instance at your main object which you pass to all other subsystems of your game. Also hold a reference inside of the subsystem so you can use it whenever you need it. => A static version shouldn't work.

Create it like this:

```
public class Assets {

    public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static final String level1 = "level1.png";

    public void load() {
        manager.load(level1, Texture.class);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        manager.dispose();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
private Assets assets;
@Override
public void create () {

    assets.load();
    //or call the assets.finishLoading();
    while(!assets.manager.update()) {
        System.out.println(assets.manager.getProgress()*100+"%");
    }

    setScreen(new GameScreen(assets)); //pass it to the gamescreen ctro!
}
```

Evenmore you can Extend your Assets class by the AssetManager and direct call the .update on the assets object. `Assets extends AssetManager`

```
public class Assets extends AssetManager{

    public static final String level1 = "level1.png";

    public void load() {
        this.load(level1, Texture.class);
    }
    //dispose not needed since you can call Assets.dispose() since the AssetManager is disposeable.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i changed my code, created an object and passed it over to the screen, but it still won't load... it keeps iterating with a progress of 0.0%, "keep loading the file"

Comment: yea it returns a float which represent the load status. Check if it returns correc tif you dont use the *100. or change it to * 100.0f

Comment: Tried not doing the *100 but nothing changed,  still 0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!Assets.manager.update()) {
    System.out.println(Assets.manager.getProgress()*100+"%");
}
```

According to your codes, it will only prints out when the assetmanager is not 100% loaded. Try remove the condition and it will actually prints from 0 directly to 1 due to loading of only one texture.